# Homebrew PHP 5.6 + Yosemite Apache 2.4

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

So, I installed [PHP 5.6 via Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php#installing-multiple-versions) on Mac OS X Yosemite Beta 6. In the official brew tap page it says, that the Apache module should be installed from `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/Cellar/php56/5.6.1/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. The thing is, I don't have ANY `$HOMEBREW_` type of environment variables, although homebrew doctor doesn't report any issues.

So I'm wondering if my install is fine and the guide is outdated or just uses `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX` to say "wherever your homebrew Cellar is" or there is something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your prefix on the command line by running `brew --prefix`

$HOMEBREW_PREFIX I think is actually defined when running brew ruby files.